# PHP DB caching, without including files

Tags: php, caching

I've been searching for a suitable `PHP` caching method for `MSSQL` results.

Most of the examples I can find suggest storing the results in an array, which would then get included to page. This seems great unless a request for the content was made at the same time as it being updated/rebuilt.

I was hoping to find something similar to ASP's application level variables, but far as I'm aware, PHP doesn't offer this functionality?

The problem I'm facing is I need to perform 6 queries on page to populate dropdown boxes. This happens on the vast majority of pages. It's also not an option to combine the queries. The cached data will also need to be rebuilt sporadically, when the system changes. This could be once a day, once a week or a month. Any advice will be greatly received, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Redis](http://redis.io/) server and [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) PHP extension to cache results fetched from database:

```php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('/tmp/redis.sock');

$sql = "SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE condition";
$sql_hash = md5($sql);
$redis_key = "dbcache:${sql_hash}";
$ttl = 3600; // values expire in 1 hour

if ($result = $redis->get($redis_key)) {
  $result = json_decode($result, true);
} else {
  $result = Db::fetchArray($sql);
  $redis->setex($redis_key, $ttl, json_encode($result));
}
```

*(Error checks skipped for clarity)*

Comment: Redis is perfect for this, as is memcached.

Comment: this is genuis! thank you so much, will have a go tomorrow